# Angular - how to send function to mat-dialog window

Tags: angular, dialog

Is possible to send function form parent to mat-dialog window and call it?

For example, I have button which onClick() opens dialog window. Next, in that window, I have two buttons:

- "CancelButton" - for close widnow without any activity,
- "Submit" - for some function like save etc.

I would like to use dialogWidnow as reusable component and sending function as parameter(?) of that dialog window but how can I do that?

Comment: Yes. You could just add an input to the dialog component, then call that input property. Functions are just objects and can be passed around like any other object. It's hard to say more than that though without seeing how you have things set up.

Comment: Hmmm, but I open dialog window by onClicl() function on button, and in that function body I use dialogWindow.open() - I am not calling <app-xxxx></app-xxxx>. So how can I drop that parameter here? By adding it to data? Or maybe how can I open dialog window by calling it like component?

Comment: Oh, yes, if you're using a dialog system that accepts data when calling `open`, pass it as part of the `data`.